# Разный результат при параллельном и последовательном запуске кода. С++, OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp

При запуске кода получаю разный результат. 
Хочу параллельно изменять разные ячейки вектора разными нитями. Ошибка проявляется тогда, когда нитей больше чем ячеек (да, я знаю, что не оптимально распараллеливать в таких случаях, но я хочу понять почему выходит разный результат).

Ошибка воспроизводится только в Visual Studio.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <omp.h>
#include "windows.h"
using namespace std;

class neuron
{
public:
neuron() //конструктор со стартовым наполнением для примера
{
    w.resize(3);
    w[0] = 0.7700484068199707;
    w[1] = 0.3427844318371112;
    w[2] = 0.6822299620512033;
    derivative.resize(3);
    derivative[0] = 0.232342234223;
    derivative[1] = 0.23232232234223;
    derivative[2] = 0.23234334231113;
}

void correction_of_scales(const double& speed)
{
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(8) //нитей больше чем ячеек
    for (size_t i = 0; i < w.size(); ++i)
    {
#pragma omp atomic
        w[i] -= speed * derivative[i]; //вот тут происходит какая то магия
       //w[i] = w[i] - speed * derivative[i]; - а вот так вот работает без ошибок
    }
}

vector <double> derivative;
vector <double> w; 
};

int main(void)
{
neuron nn;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) //сто раз подряд меняем вектор
    nn.correction_of_scales(0.01);

for (int i = 0; i < nn.w.size(); i++)
    cout << scientific << setprecision(15) << nn.w[i] << endl;

system("pause");
}
```

Вот что выводится при последовательном запуске

```
5.377061725969665e-01  
1.104621094948808e-01  
4.498866197400767e-01
```

А вот что выводится при паралельном запуске

```
-6.24004998518318e-01  
1.104621094948808e-01  
4.498866197400767e-01
```

Comment: atomic ничего не гарантирует насчет выражения, он защищает только переменную. Вам скорее нужен reduction.

Comment: @AndreySv, оператор reduction отвечает за другое. В во все нити копируется объект и в конце можно например сложить все элементы.

Comment: Да, reduction для обобщения у Вас тут его действительно нет, судя по тексту в разных потоках Вы хотите модифицировать разные значения, т.е. значения уже разделены. Похоже достаточно только `#pragma omp parallel for `.

Answer (score 0):

Это была ошибка в Visual Studio 
[developercommunity.visualstudio.com](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/608908/different-results-when-running-code-in-parallel-an.html)

В Visual Studio в конструкции parallel for нельзя использовать size_t, только int.

Comment: Хорошо бы перенести подробности ошибки в ответ)